# procedure gets stuck after running similar steps in a loop

Tags: oracle11g

i have a procedure below.

the NR_VTMATCH_SQLS table just has pieces of code to build the queries, about 700 lines.

This is a procedure that matches 2 tables on 700 combinations of name, SSN, TIN, DOB, Address, CityState, ZIP.

combinations look like this, basically i'm trying to match on all possible combinations going from strongest to weakest

```
518. First Name, First 4 letters of Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, DOB, ZIP, City, State
516. First Name, Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, DOB, ZIP, City, State
514. First Name, First 4 letters of Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, Address, ZIP, City, State
512. First Name, Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, Address, ZIP, City, State
510. First Name, First 4 letters of Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, Address, DOB, City, State
508. First Name, Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, Address, DOB, City, State
506. First Name, First 4 letters of Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, Address, DOB, ZIP
504. First Name, Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, Address, DOB, ZIP
502. First Name, First 4 letters of Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, Address, DOB, ZIP, City, State
500. First Name, Last Name, SSN, ViantID, TIN, Address, DOB, ZIP, City, State
```

the tables that i'm matching are pretty huge, 20M rows against 10M rows, and as you can tell, in every step i'm creating a version of those tables, so in every step a table with 20M rows is created and then dropped.

I know this is a horrible way of doing it, very taxing, i used to have a merge query instead, no creating tables and ran into the same problem.

the problem is that every XX iterations it gets stuck. it's almost as if some memory somewhere gets filled up and a step hangs. there's nothing wrong with the step itself, once i cancel the procedure - i can run the step by hand and it takes 2 mins.
if i restart it from that step - then another XX steps it will hang again (in the latest run XX=about 50).

am i right that something is being filled up? if so, then what is it? and what can i do about it?

if I'm wrong then do you have any ideas?

thank you

my procedure

```
   DECLARE
    CURSOR CurRec  IS
        SELECT  MatchedID
                ,FacPracGrp
                ,SQL1
                ,SQL2
                ,SQL3
                ,SQL4
            FROM NR_VTMATCH_SQLS
           WHERE OriginalMatchedOn NOT BETWEEN 299 AND 499
        ORDER BY AutoID;
    SQLS CurRec%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN CurRec;
    LOOP
        FETCH CurRec INTO SQLS;
        EXIT WHEN CurRec%NOTFOUND;
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE NR_VTMATCH_TMP';
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
                    RAISE;
                END IF;



                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE NR_VTMATCH_TMP AS
       SELECT    UniqueID
               ,' || SQLS.sql1 || '            FROM NR_VTMATCH_PROVS pr
          WHERE  ' || SQLS.sql4 || ' ';

                COMMIT;



                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
                       'INSERT INTO NR_VTMATCH_MATCHED
       SELECT --+append
             DISTINCT mt.UniqueID ,mt.FacPracGrp, pr.UniqueID  ,  '''
                    || SQLS.sql3
                    || ''', '''
                    || sqls.FacPracGrp
                    || '''  FROM NR_VTMATCH_MATCH mt, NR_VTMATCH_TMP pr   WHERE         1 = 1   '
                    || SQLS.sql2
                    || ' ';



                COMMIT;


                DELETE FROM NR_VTMATCH_MATCH
                      WHERE UniqueID IN (SELECT UniqueID FROM NR_VTMATCH_MATCHED);


                COMMIT;
        END;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CurRec;
END;
```

EDIT

i just noticed that it's also skipping every 2nd combination, you can see the gaps in numbers. this is really weird, any ideas? or should i post a separate question on this?

Comment: Creating and dropping objects at runtime is painful anyway; have you considered using a global temporary table instead, as a permanent object? Or a collection, though you may have too much data in it for that to be practical perhaps, though you could maybe work in batches. I'm not sure why you're using temporary data at all though; can't you just make the subquery in your delete identify all the IDs directly from the source tables?

Comment: It's all for speed. I tried many different solutions and this was the fastest. I don't have to delete anything either. I thought if I delete used records it'd be faster. I was desperate, my run time was 48 hours. I'm researching global temp and collection. I didn't know about either of those.